# Finding indices of NetCDF dataset based on condition of second dataset with same gridscale, but different gridpoints

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am creating a model where some climate values are calculated for each gridcell in a 3x3km gridscale. I only need to do the calculations in specific gridcells where a condition is met (in this case gridcells that contain forests). Information on land-use is available in a different Netcdf4 dataset, also on a 3x3km gridscale, but with slightly different gridpoints.

Is there a way for me to select specifically the gridcells in file A that overlap or at least are closest to the gridcells in file B where the condition is met?

As of now I use this code to subset file A data for a specific lat-long region:

```
coords_xy = Dataset(file_A_path, "r")
coords_x = coords_xy['lon'][0,:]
coords_y = coords_xy['lat'][:,0]
dataset_T2MEAN = coords_xy['tas'][0,:,:]

all_indexes_XLAT = []
for i in range(0, len(coords_y)) :
    if coords_y[i] >= min_xlat and coords_y[i] <= max_xlong:
        all_indexes_XLAT.append(i)

all_indexes_XLONG = []
for z in range(0,len(coords_x)):
    if coords_x[z] >= min_xlong and coords_x[z] <= max_xlong:
        all_indexes_XLONG.append(z)


number_of_latitudinal_degrees = len(coords_y)
number_of_longitudinal_degrees = len(coords_x)

coords_shape = np.zeros(shape = (number_of_latitudinal_degrees, number_of_longitudinal_degrees), dtype = "float32")

for i in all_indexes_XLAT:
    for j in all_indexes_XLONG:
      coords_shape[i,j] = dataset_T2MEAN[i,j]

indexes_coords = np.asarray(np.where(coords_shape >= -100)).T

for i in range(0, len(indexes_coords)-1):
    index_y = indexes_coords[i,0]
    index_x = indexes_coords[i,1]
```

This is the code I use to subset file C with file B, where the gridcells of file B and C are the exact same (with difference in spatial range):

```
coords_xy = Dataset(file_C_path, "r")
coords_x = coords_xy['XLONG'][0,:]
coords_y = coords_xy['XLAT'][:,0]

all_indexes_XLAT = []
for i in range(0, len(coords_y)) :
    if coords_y[i] >= min_xlat and coords_y[i] <= max_xlat:
        all_indexes_XLAT.append(i)

all_indexes_XLONG = []
for z in range(0,len(coords_x)):
    if coords_x[z] >= min_xlong:
        all_indexes_XLONG.append(z)

dataset_LU_XLAT = Dataset(file_B_path, 'r')['XLAT_M'][0,:,0]
dataset_LU_XLONG = Dataset(file_B_path, 'r')['XLONG_M'][0,0,:]
dataset_LU = Dataset(file_B_path, 'r')['LU_INDEX'][0,:,:]

all_indexes_LU_XLONG = []
for i in range(0, len(dataset_LU_XLONG)) :
    if dataset_LU_XLONG[i] >= min_xlong and dataset_LU_XLONG[i] <= max_xlong:
        all_indexes_LU_XLONG.append(i)

all_indexes_LU_XLAT = []
for i in range(0, len(dataset_LU_XLAT)) :
    if dataset_LU_XLAT[i] >= min_xlat and dataset_LU_XLAT[i] <= max_xlat:
        all_indexes_LU_XLAT.append(i)

LU_WRFoutput_shape = np.zeros(shape = (number_of_latitudinal_degrees, number_of_longitudinal_degrees), dtype = "float32")
for i in all_indexes_LU_XLAT:
    for j in all_indexes_LU_XLONG:
        LU_WRFoutput_shape[i,j] = dataset_LU[i,j]

indexes_condition_LU = np.asarray(np.where((LU_WRFoutput_shape >= 11) & (LU_WRFoutput_shape <= 15))).T

for i in range(0, len(indexes_condition_LU)-1):
    index_y = indexes_condition_LU[i,0]
    index_x = indexes_condition_LU[i,1]
```

Ncdump -h output of file A:

```
netcdf file_A {
dimensions:
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (365 currently)
        bnds = 2 ;
        x = 621 ;
        y = 837 ;
variables:
        double time(time) ;
                time:standard_name = "time" ;
                time:long_name = "time" ;
                time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
                time:units = "days since 1949-12-1 00:00:00" ;
                time:calendar = "standard" ;
                time:axis = "T" ;
        double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;
        double lon(y, x) ;
                lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
                lon:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
        double lat(y, x) ;
                lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
                lat:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
        double x(x) ;
                x:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
                x:long_name = "X Coordinate Of Projection" ;
                x:units = "m" ;
                x:axis = "X" ;
        double y(y) ;
                y:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
                y:long_name = "Y Coordinate Of Projection" ;
                y:units = "m" ;
                y:axis = "Y" ;
        int Lambert_Conformal ;
                Lambert_Conformal:grid_mapping_name = "lambert_conformal_conic" ;
                Lambert_Conformal:standard_parallel = 62.2 ;
                Lambert_Conformal:longitude_of_central_meridian = 10. ;
                Lambert_Conformal:latitude_of_projection_origin = 62.2 ;
                Lambert_Conformal:false_easting = 669102.401911107 ;
                Lambert_Conformal:false_northing = 1265895.12734457 ;
                Lambert_Conformal:earth_radius = 6371220. ;
                Lambert_Conformal:proj4 = "+proj=lcca +lat_1=62.200000 +lat_0=62.200000 +lon_0=10.000000 +k_0=1.0 +x_0=669102.401911 +y_0=1265895.127345 +a=6371220.000000 +b=6371220.000000" ;
        float height ;
                height:standard_name = "height" ;
                height:long_name = "height" ;
                height:units = "m" ;
                height:positive = "up" ;
                height:axis = "Z" ;
        float tas(time, y, x) ;
                tas:standard_name = "air_temperature" ;
                tas:long_name = "Near-Surface Air Temperature" ;
                tas:units = "K" ;
                tas:grid_mapping = "Lambert_Conformal" ;
                tas:coordinates = "height lat lon" ;
                tas:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
                tas:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
                tas:cell_methods = "time: point" ;

// global attributes:
                :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.7" ;
                :institute_id = "SMHI" ;
                :experiment_id = "evaluation" ;
                :frequency = "day" ;
                :driving_model_id = "ECMWF-ERAINT" ;
                :creation_date = "2020-09-15-T15:46:15Z" ;
                :experiment = "Evaluation run with reanalysis forcing" ;
                :driving_experiment = "ERA-Interim downscaled by HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM38-ALADIN to 12km over Central-North Europe which is further downscaled by HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM38-AROME to 3 km" ;
                :driving_model_ensemble_member = "r1i1p1" ;
                :driving_experiment_name = "evaluation" ;
                :rcm_model_id = "HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM38-ALADIN" ;
                :rcm_version_id = "v1" ;
                :rcm_domain = "NEU-12" ;
                :rcm_institute_id = "HCLIMcom-SMHI" ;
                :rcm_institution = "Rossby Center, SMHI, Sweden in collaboration with the HCLIM-Community" ;
                :rcm_contact = "danijel.belusic@smhi.se" ;
                :cprcm_model_id = "HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM38-AROME" ;
                :cprcm_domain = "NEU-3" ;
                :cprcm_institute_id = "HCLIMcom-SMHI" ;
                :cprcm_institution = "Rossby Center, SMHI, Sweden in collaboration with the HCLIM-Community" ;
                :cprcm_nesting_information = "x2yn2v1" ;
                :cprcm_nesting_comment = "Configuration differences (CPRCM/RCM). Dynamics: non-hydrostatic/hydrostatic. Physics package: AROME/ALADIN. Sub grid scale orography parameterisation: None/Z01D. Turbulence scheme: HARATU/CBR. Boundary condition update: 3-hourly/6-hourly" ;
                :cprcm_contact = "danijel.belusic@smhi.se" ;
                :nesting_levels = "2" ;
                :project_id = "NORCP" ;
                :product = "output" ;
                :references = "https://www.hirlam.org/trac/wiki/HarmonieClimate" ;
                :tracking_id = "95641239-2908-4593-bcc5-1c4ec6dc2934" ;
                :rossby_comment = "ERA-Interim | HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM38-ALADIN 12km Central-North Europe | HCLIMcom-SMHI-HCLIM-AROME 3 km Northern Europe |" ;
                :rossby_run_id = "HCLIM38-AROME_v1_HCLIM38-ALADIN-NEU-12_evaluation_r1i1p1_NEU-3" ;
                :rossby_path = "/nobackup/rossby21/rossby/joint_exp/norcp/NorCP_AROME_ERAI_ALADIN_1997_2017/netcdf/" ;
                :history = "Fri Jan 19 15:33:12 2024: cdo daymean ./1998/SurfTemp_HCLIM3_1998_hourly.nc ./1998/SurfTemp_HCLIM3_1998_daily.nc" ;
                :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
}
```

Ncdump -h output of file B:

```
netcdf file_B {
dimensions:
    Times = UNLIMITED ; // (365 currently)
    bnds = 2 ;
    west_east = 465 ;
    south_north = 600 ;
variables:
        double Times(Times) ;
                Times:standard_name = "time" ;
                Times:bounds = "Times_bnds" ;
                Times:units = "day as %Y%m%d.%f" ;
                Times:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
                Times:axis = "T" ;
        double Times_bnds(Times, bnds) ;
        float XLONG(south_north, west_east) ;
                XLONG:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                XLONG:long_name = "longitude" ;
                XLONG:units = "degrees_east" ;
                XLONG:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
        float XLAT(south_north, west_east) ;
                XLAT:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                XLAT:long_name = "latitude" ;
                XLAT:units = "degrees_north" ;
                XLAT:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
        float T2MEAN(Times, south_north, west_east) ;
                T2MEAN:units = "K" ;
                T2MEAN:coordinates = "XLAT XLONG" ;
                T2MEAN:cell_methods = "Times: mean" ;
                T2MEAN:FieldType = 104 ;
                T2MEAN:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
                T2MEAN:description = "MEAN TEMPERATURE AT 2M HEIGHT IN DIAGNOSTIC OUTPUT INTERVAL" ;
                T2MEAN:stagger = "" ;

// global attributes:
                :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
                :history = "Fri Jan 26 12:26:15 2024: cdo selyear,1998 /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.1996-2005.nc /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/1998/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.1998.nc\n",
                        "Fri Jan 26 12:21:34 2024: cdo daymean /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.3hrly.1996-2005.nc /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.1996-2005.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 09:31:30 2019: cdo mergetime control.T2MEAN.1995.nc control.T2MEAN.1996.nc control.T2MEAN.1997.nc control.T2MEAN.1998.nc control.T2MEAN.1999.nc control.T2MEAN.2000.nc control.T2MEAN.2001.nc control.T2MEAN.2002.nc control.T2MEAN.2003.nc control.T2MEAN.2004.nc control.T2MEAN.2005.nc control.T2MEAN.historical.3hrly.1996-2005.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 09:19:28 2019: cdo mergetime T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-02_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-03_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-04_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-05_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-06_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-07_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-08_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-09_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-10_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-11_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-12_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-13_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-14_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-15_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-16_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-17_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-18_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-19_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-20_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-21_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-22_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-23_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-24_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-25_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-26_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-27_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-28_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-29_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-30_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-31_00:00:00 control.T2MEAN.1995.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 08:07:16 2019: cdo selname,T2MEAN wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00" ;
                :TITLE = " OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.9.1.1 MODEL" ;
                :START_DATE = "1995-01-01_00:00:00" ;
                :WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION = 466 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_GRID_DIMENSION = 601 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_GRID_DIMENSION = 51 ;
                :DX = 3112.969f ;
                :DY = 3112.969f ;
                :GRIDTYPE = "C" ;
                :DIFF_OPT = 2 ;
                :KM_OPT = 4 ;
                :DAMP_OPT = 3 ;
                :DAMPCOEF = 0.2f ;
                :KHDIF = 0.f ;
                :KVDIF = 0.f ;
                :MP_PHYSICS = 8 ;
                :RA_LW_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :RA_SW_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :SF_SFCLAY_PHYSICS = 1 ;
                :SF_SURFACE_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :BL_PBL_PHYSICS = 1 ;
                :CU_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SF_LAKE_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SURFACE_INPUT_SOURCE = 1 ;
                :SST_UPDATE = 1 ;
                :GRID_FDDA = 0 ;
                :GFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
                :GFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
                :GRID_SFDDA = 0 ;
                :SGFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
                :SGFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
                :HYPSOMETRIC_OPT = 2 ;
                :USE_THETA_M = 0 ;
                :GWD_OPT = 0 ;
                :SF_URBAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SF_OCEAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 465 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_STAG = 466 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 600 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_STAG = 601 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 50 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_STAG = 51 ;
                :GRID_ID = 1 ;
                :PARENT_ID = 1 ;
                :I_PARENT_START = 195 ;
                :J_PARENT_START = 120 ;
                :PARENT_GRID_RATIO = 5 ;
                :DT = 20.f ;
                :CEN_LAT = 63.00437f ;
                :CEN_LON = 8.76868f ;
                :TRUELAT1 = 1.e+20f ;
                :TRUELAT2 = 1.e+20f ;
                :MOAD_CEN_LAT = 53.39108f ;
                :STAND_LON = -31.f ;
                :POLE_LAT = 36.75f ;
                :POLE_LON = 16.f ;
                :GMT = 0.f ;
                :JULYR = 1995 ;
                :JULDAY = 1 ;
                :MAP_PROJ = 6 ;
                :MAP_PROJ_CHAR = "Cylindrical Equidistant" ;
                :MMINLU = "USGS" ;
                :NUM_LAND_CAT = 28 ;
                :ISWATER = 16 ;
                :ISLAKE = 28 ;
                :ISICE = 24 ;
                :ISURBAN = 1 ;
                :ISOILWATER = 14 ;
                :HYBRID_OPT = -1 ;
                :ETAC = 0.f ;
                :frequency = "day" ;
                :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
}
```

Ncdump -h output of file C:

```
netcdf file_C {
dimensions:
        Times = UNLIMITED ; // (366 currently)
        bnds = 2 ;
        west_east = 465 ;
        south_north = 600 ;
variables:
        double Times(Times) ;
                Times:standard_name = "time" ;
                Times:bounds = "Times_bnds" ;
                Times:units = "day as %Y%m%d.%f" ;
                Times:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
                Times:axis = "T" ;
        double Times_bnds(Times, bnds) ;
        float XLONG(south_north, west_east) ;
                XLONG:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                XLONG:long_name = "longitude" ;
                XLONG:units = "degrees_east" ;
                XLONG:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
        float XLAT(south_north, west_east) ;
                XLAT:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                XLAT:long_name = "latitude" ;
                XLAT:units = "degrees_north" ;
                XLAT:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
        float T2MEAN(Times, south_north, west_east) ;
                T2MEAN:units = "K" ;
                T2MEAN:coordinates = "XLAT XLONG" ;
                T2MEAN:cell_methods = "Times: mean" ;
                T2MEAN:FieldType = 104 ;
                T2MEAN:MemoryOrder = "XY " ;
                T2MEAN:description = "MEAN TEMPERATURE AT 2M HEIGHT IN DIAGNOSTIC OUTPUT INTERVAL" ;
                T2MEAN:stagger = "" ;

// global attributes:
                :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
                :history = "Fri Jan 26 12:26:18 2024: cdo selyear,2000 /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.1996-2005.nc /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/2000/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.2000.nc\n",
                        "Fri Jan 26 12:21:34 2024: cdo daymean /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.3hrly.1996-2005.nc /cluster/work/users/elsri/Naturact/Input/WRFoutput/control/control.d02.T2MEAN.historical.daily.1996-2005.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 09:31:30 2019: cdo mergetime control.T2MEAN.1995.nc control.T2MEAN.1996.nc control.T2MEAN.1997.nc control.T2MEAN.1998.nc control.T2MEAN.1999.nc control.T2MEAN.2000.nc control.T2MEAN.2001.nc control.T2MEAN.2002.nc control.T2MEAN.2003.nc control.T2MEAN.2004.nc control.T2MEAN.2005.nc control.T2MEAN.historical.3hrly.1996-2005.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 09:19:28 2019: cdo mergetime T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-02_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-03_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-04_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-05_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-06_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-07_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-08_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-09_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-10_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-11_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-12_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-13_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-14_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-15_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-16_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-17_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-18_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-19_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-20_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-21_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-22_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-23_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-24_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-25_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-26_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-27_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-28_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-29_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-30_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-31_00:00:00 control.T2MEAN.1995.nc\n",
                        "Fri Apr 05 08:07:16 2019: cdo selname,T2MEAN wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00 T2MEAN_wrfxtrm_d02_1995-12-01_00:00:00" ;
                :TITLE = " OUTPUT FROM WRF V3.9.1.1 MODEL" ;
                :START_DATE = "1995-01-01_00:00:00" ;
                :WEST-EAST_GRID_DIMENSION = 466 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_GRID_DIMENSION = 601 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_GRID_DIMENSION = 51 ;
                :DX = 3112.969f ;
                :DY = 3112.969f ;
                :GRIDTYPE = "C" ;
                :DIFF_OPT = 2 ;
                :KM_OPT = 4 ;
                :DAMP_OPT = 3 ;
                :DAMPCOEF = 0.2f ;
                :KHDIF = 0.f ;
                :KVDIF = 0.f ;
                :MP_PHYSICS = 8 ;
                :RA_LW_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :RA_SW_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :SF_SFCLAY_PHYSICS = 1 ;
                :SF_SURFACE_PHYSICS = 4 ;
                :BL_PBL_PHYSICS = 1 ;
                :CU_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SF_LAKE_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SURFACE_INPUT_SOURCE = 1 ;
                :SST_UPDATE = 1 ;
                :GRID_FDDA = 0 ;
                :GFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
                :GFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
                :GRID_SFDDA = 0 ;
                :SGFDDA_INTERVAL_M = 0 ;
                :SGFDDA_END_H = 0 ;
                :HYPSOMETRIC_OPT = 2 ;
                :USE_THETA_M = 0 ;
                :GWD_OPT = 0 ;
                :SF_URBAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :SF_OCEAN_PHYSICS = 0 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 465 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :WEST-EAST_PATCH_END_STAG = 466 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 600 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :SOUTH-NORTH_PATCH_END_STAG = 601 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_UNSTAG = 1 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_UNSTAG = 50 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_START_STAG = 1 ;
                :BOTTOM-TOP_PATCH_END_STAG = 51 ;
                :GRID_ID = 1 ;
                :PARENT_ID = 1 ;
                :I_PARENT_START = 195 ;
                :J_PARENT_START = 120 ;
                :PARENT_GRID_RATIO = 5 ;
                :DT = 20.f ;
                :CEN_LAT = 63.00437f ;
                :CEN_LON = 8.76868f ;
                :TRUELAT1 = 1.e+20f ;
                :TRUELAT2 = 1.e+20f ;
                :MOAD_CEN_LAT = 53.39108f ;
                :STAND_LON = -31.f ;
                :POLE_LAT = 36.75f ;
                :POLE_LON = 16.f ;
                :GMT = 0.f ;
                :JULYR = 1995 ;
                :JULDAY = 1 ;
                :MAP_PROJ = 6 ;
                :MAP_PROJ_CHAR = "Cylindrical Equidistant" ;
                :MMINLU = "USGS" ;
                :NUM_LAND_CAT = 28 ;
                :ISWATER = 16 ;
                :ISLAKE = 28 ;
                :ISICE = 24 ;
                :ISURBAN = 1 ;
                :ISOILWATER = 14 ;
                :HYBRID_OPT = -1 ;
                :ETAC = 0.f ;
                :frequency = "day" ;
                :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 2.0.6 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)";
}
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear how you want to fix the problem. Can you not just regrid the second file and append it to the first? That way you can access the "forest" variable and use it in any calcs

Comment: How would you regrid the second file to match the first?